# Covering map of the Cylinder

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

> **Question:** Is there a covering map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ ?

I picture the cylinder $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ as a roll of gift wrap that one "rolls the plane" onto (just a thought). We proved that $\mathbb{R} \to S^1, x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}x}$ is a covering map of the unit circle. But I can't figure out whether the title question is true or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

$$\varphi : (x,y) \mapsto (e^{2\pi i x},y)?$$

Comment: What does the fibre (preimage) $\varphi^{-1}[\{(x,y)\}] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ of a $(x,y) \in S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ look like? Wouldn't it be something like $\mathbb{Z} \times \{y\}$ ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Is there a general method to construct the "admissible" neighbourhoods around $(x,y) \in S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ ? A covering map is caracterized by its admissible open sets that are homeomorphically acted upon by the map... (I don't quite see how to construct these here, though I suspect that for the first component, one will have to exclude the antipodal point $-x$ from the set)